# Configuring yslow on Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, yslow

Could I get some help on configuring Jenkins to use yslow?

I saw on the lightning speach for yslow that it can be implemented with CI, but it didn't give very much information on how one would go about doing this. I've done quite a bit of searching on google for yslow and CI or jenkins, and have been unable to find anything.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, seem like [someone destroyed YSlow for PahntomJS wiki page](https://twitter.com/marcelduran/status/223132634807668736) but it's back again, check it out at: https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/wiki/PhantomJS

There was Jenkins screenshot but no step-by-step integration, I just updated the wiki with the following:

---

Once you have Jenkins, PhantomJS and YSlow for PhantomJS installed and working properly, just add the following shell command into your building process:

`phantomjs /tmp/yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f junit http://built-page-here > yslow.xml`

In line above:

- YSlow for PhantomJS script is located at `/tmp/yslow.js`
- `-i grade` specifies that all rules will be tested
- `-threshold "B"` specifies the lowest acceptable score for all rules as well as overall score
- `-f junit` specifies the output format for Jenkins
- `http://built-url-here` is the reachable built page url of your project
- `yslow.xml` is the output results in junit format

If you have TAP plugin installed (via Jenkins plugin manager), you can replace the line above or add another test as follows:

`phantomjs /tmp/yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f tap http://built-page-here > yslow.tap`
In line above:

- YSlow for PhantomJS script is located at `/tmp/yslow.js`
- `-i grade` specifies that all rules will be tested
- `-threshold "B"` specifies the lowest acceptable score for all rules as well as overall score
- `-f tap` specifies the output format for TAP Jenkins plugin
- `http://built-url-here` is the reachable built page url of your project
- `yslow.tap` is the output results in TAP format

Make sure you publish JUnit and/or TAP results report in the post-build actions pointing to the output test results file(s), e.g: yslow.xml, yslow.tap, etc.

---

Comment: @marcelduran Are you aware of documentation to integrate yslow with TeamCity for Network Monitoring?

Thanks,