# YSlow Phantomjs and Jenkins jobs failing, but analysis successful

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, yslow

I'm going through the tutorial on YSlow and Phantom js in Jenkins here: http://yslow.org/phantomjs/

Everything appears to be working great except the Jenkins builds are failing.  I *think* this is due to the violations that YSlow is finding (6 for the particular site I am measuring).  I'd rather have the build be successful (or unstable) vs. failed though

Is that possible with this or will I have to resort to something like the postgroovy or text finder plugin?

This is the console output:

```
phantomjs.exe yslow.js -i grade -t 50 --format junit http://www.somesite.com 1>yslow.xml 
D:\Apps\Jenkins\workspace\YSlow_Test>exit 6 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-zero exit code at the *end* of your **Execute Windows batch command** build step will result in build step being marked as `failure`.

To have the build step marked as `success`, you need an exit code of `0`. I don't know anything about "yslow" or "phantomjs" and why they are giving you exit code of non-zero, but from "batch" side of things, you need only write `exit 0` at the end of your build step if you want to overwrite the exit code of your `phantomjs` command.

You can then use **[Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** to parse the console log and mark build as `unstable` when certain conditions are met.

Reading over this answer, **[Configuring yslow on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419284/configuring-yslow-on-jenkins)** looks like you need [**TAP plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TAP+Plugin) to have the functionality of unit testing marking the build as unstable automatically

Comment: Thanks - makes sense.  As a FYI you can use either TAP or JUnit to display the results.